# Как реализовать чтение команд из файла?

Tags: java, ооп

Пишу консольное приложение для работы с коллекцией, для управления коллекцией реализуются команды, которые вводятся с консоли:

- `add_element` - добавляет элемент к в коллекцию
- `clear_collection` - очищает коллекцию
- `save_collection 'file_name'` - сохранение коллекции в указанный файл
- `script 'file_name'` - считывает команды с указанного файла и выполняет их.

Коллекция `ArrayList` содержит элементы класса:

```
public class Worker {
    String name;
    String surName;
    int age;
    String jobTitle;
    int experience;
}
```

Команда `add_element` выполняется так: при вызове этой команды происходит печать строки "Введите имя :" и соответственно пользователь должен ввести имя, далее аналогично еще 4 строки-приглашения для ввода остальных 4 параметров коллекции.

Вопрос: как реализовать команду `script 'file_name'`? То есть, как реализовать чтение команд из файла? В файле, например, содержатся строки (каждая с новой строки) - команда `add_element` и 5 параметров:

```
add
name
surName
25
ml
3
```

Понятно, что просто построчное чтение не подойдет, из-за команды `add`, так как она вызывает свои строки-приглашения, нужно как-то реализовать рекурсию, но как?

Comment: А в файле может быть только команда `add_element` или другие тоже? И гарантируется ли, что строки, которые являются параметрами (имя, фамилия, ...) не равны ни одной из команд по своему названию?

Comment: Да, могут содержаться другие команды. Гарантируется, что ни одна из команд не равна по названию с параметрами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С использованием рекурсии получилось вот так:

```
class Task {

    private final List<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add_element(List<String> lines, int pos) {
        workers.add(new Worker(
                lines.get(++pos), lines.get(++pos), Integer.parseInt(lines.get(++pos)),
                lines.get(++pos), Integer.parseInt(lines.get(++pos))
        ));
    }

    public void clear_collection() {
        workers.clear();
    }

    public void save_collection(String fileName) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName))) {
            for (Worker worker : workers) {
                writer.write(worker + "\n");
            }
        }
    }

    public void script(String fileName) throws IOException {
        int pos = 0;
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName));
        while (pos < lines.size()) {
            if (lines.get(pos).equals("add_element")) {
                add_element(lines, pos);
                pos += 5;
            } else if (lines.get(pos).equals("clear_collection")) {
                clear_collection();
                pos++;
            } else if (lines.get(pos).contains("save_collection")) {
                String line = lines.get(pos);
                save_collection(line.substring(line.indexOf("'") + 1, line.lastIndexOf("'")));
                pos++;
            } else if (lines.get(pos).contains("script")) {
                String line = lines.get(pos);
                script(line.substring(line.indexOf("'") + 1, line.lastIndexOf("'")));
                pos++;
            } else {
                pos++;
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Worker> getWorkers() {
        return workers;
    }
}
```

Все 4 команды разбиты по методам. Метод `add_element()` добавляет в список очередного `Worker`-а, метод `clear_collection()` просто очищает список, метод `save_collection()` сохраняет список в указанный файл, занося туда построчно элементы списка.

Метод `script()` считывает передаваемый в него файл в список строк, которым дальше и оперирует. Переменная `pos` означает текущую позицию для взятия из списка очередной строки. После выполнения сохранения, очистки списка и команды `script` она наращивается на единицу, а после выполнения команды `add_element` - на пять.

Конечно, чтобы программа работала, должны соблюдаться следующие ограничения:

- "скриптовый" файл не содержит лишних символов
- после команды `add_element` обязательно идёт 5 строк, означающих параметры
- после команд `script` и `clear_collection` имя желаемого файла заключается в одинарные кавычки `'`.

Если эти условия соблюдаются, то команда `script` отрабатывает правильно, в том числе учитывая рекурсивный вызов.